# How do I check for child theme files first using include, before going to parent theme?

Tags: wordpress, inheritance, parent-child, child-theming

I'm creating a WordPress child theme based on an existing parent theme, and I'd like to have any same-named file I put in my child theme directory take priority over the file in the parent theme directory. I thought this was how parent/child theming was set up in WP but I have hit a bump.

According to the [WordPress codex on Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Template_Files), it says:

> **Template Files** 
>  
>   If you want to change more than just the stylesheet,
>   your child theme can override any file in the parent theme: simply
>   include a file of the same name in the child theme directory, and it
>   will override the equivalent file in the parent theme directory when
>   your site loads.

In one of my files (header.php), there is an include that looks like this:

```
include get_parent_theme_file_path("folder/file.php")
```

Even though I have a duplicate-named-but-modified version of that file.php in my child theme, it still uses the version in my parent theme. According to the same codex, their recommendation for targeting a child theme file specifically is to use get_stylesheet_directory(), so it would look like this:

```
include (get_stylesheet_directory()."/folder/file.php");
```

I understand that the purpose of a function called "get_parent_theme_file_path()" is to ignore the parent/child relationship and just get the parent theme version, so without replacing that with a function that explicitly gets a file in my child theme (ie. get_stylesheet_directory), **is there a way I can have some sort of universal get_path() function that checks for child first, if it doesn't exist, get parent version?**

By the way, I read [this Q&A on "get_parent_theme_file_path vs. get_template_directory"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257597/get-parent-theme-file-path-vs-get-template-directory/257613), but their solution was to use parent_theme_file filters, but that isn't dynamic, and would require me to write a filter function for every child file I want it to use.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you have now in your themes folder your parent theme folder and child theme folder, right? Do your child folder has at least a functions.php and style.css file? Does your style.css file has the correct header comment to reference the parent theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone on wordpress.stackexchange pointed out the use of [`locate_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/), which retrieves the name of the highest priority template file that exists.

> Searches in the STYLESHEETPATH before TEMPLATEPATH and wp-includes/theme-compat so that themes which inherit from a parent theme can just overload one file.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried something like this:

```
add_filter( 'parent_theme_file_path', function( $path, $file ) {
    return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $file;
}, 10, 2 );
```

This should override the parent theme path without the need to write a function for every file.

If you want to make sure `get_parent_theme_file_path()` still works for parent theme files that are not overriden in your child theme, you could do a simple check:

```
add_filter( 'parent_theme_file_path', function( $path, $file ) {
    if ( !file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $file ) ) {
        return $path;
    }
    return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $file;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but then I can't use the `parent_theme_file_path()` function at all, which may be used in the parent or child theme later on.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Fantastic answer, this solution should really be available in the core Wordpress code. The ability to always take the child theme file if it exists seems standard to me.